# Efficient PHP way to return first part of string with multiple delimiter characters for a large number of rows

Tags: php, string, split, delimiter

This is a common question but asking from a performance point of view.

How can we return the first part of string until a space or * is found? In a single line code.
I saw many ways like strstr, strtok, explode etc but all of them supports just one delimiter if i am not wrong.

I have date written into text like :

```
29-Apr-2021*  
02-09-2019 12:00:00
```

strip the last part from * or space to return `29-Apr-2021 and 02-09-2019`

I have about 5000 rows to loop over, each row has 5 date fields to correct.So I need fastest way to achieve this. 
I read about preg_split but i guess this is going to be slow.

Comment: So how fast is your current way? You say you guess 5000 rows and 5 date fields would be too slow. 5000 rows are not that much. Do you have any goals set for the speed? Or what is the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the fastest way, but you don't have to use preg_split. You could use [strtok](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) which supports multiple delimiters.

> Note that you may put multiple tokens in the token parameter. The
>   string will be tokenized when any one of the characters in the
>   argument is found.

```
$strings = [
    "29-Apr-2021*",
    "02-09-2019 12:00:00"
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    echo strtok($str, " *") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
29-Apr-2021
02-09-2019
```

[Php example](https://3v4l.org/JAbMi)